# Symfony Doctrine: Use MongoDB ObjectId Prikey as MySQL ORM Column Type

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm porting over a project that used MongoDB, so of course all data used Mongo's ObjectId type as the primary `_id` field. Now that I'm redefining the schema with Doctrine ORM, I can't simply use the `integer` type as the primary key because apps using my REST service have stored that `_id` value (a string, i.e. "a98h98fsdf87g87df").

Basically, how can I do something similar to:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ObjectId
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
 */
protected $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question if anyone else ever has a use for this.

I basically enabled the `mongodb.so` PHP extension so that I could use the `ObjectId` class in my own generator.

First I created my custom generator:

```
<?php

namespace App\ORM\Generators;

use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ObjectIdGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator {

    public function __construct(){}

    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity){
        return new ObjectId();
    }

}
```

Then I pointed to that from my entity.

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(length=24)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="App\ORM\Generators\ObjectIdGenerator")
 */
protected $id;
```

Simple as that!